# Split into train/test a sample equally in all three nested lineal models

Tags: r

I have mapped lineal models, and i would like to check how sussesful are they, so I would like to split my data into train and test, but I am not sure about where to add that.
At the moment I have something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df<-iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest() %>% 
              mutate(model=map(data,~lm(formula= "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width",data=.x)))

final<-vector()

for(i in 1:length(df$model)){

  the_model<-df$model[[i]]
  value<-broom::glance(the_model)%>% select(adj.r.squared)
  final[i]<-value[[1]]

}
```

I know I should split my data before the "for", and then I should check its sussess inside it.
But I dont know how to split them inside the nested groups, in order to have 75% of each group and not risk to have something like 80% of one group, 60% of another and 75% of the last one.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(class = sample(rep(c('train', 'test'), c(n() * 0.8, n() * 0.2)))) %>%
  group_by(class, .add = TRUE) %>%
  nest() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = class, values_from = data) %>%
  mutate(model= map(train,~lm(formula= "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width",data=.x)))

#  Species    train             test              model 
#  <fct>      <list>            <list>            <list>
#1 setosa     <tibble [40 × 4]> <tibble [10 × 4]> <lm>  
#2 versicolor <tibble [40 × 4]> <tibble [10 × 4]> <lm>  
#3 virginica  <tibble [40 × 4]> <tibble [10 × 4]> <lm>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronan, but I am still having the same problem. My overall sample in this case would be splited in 0.8/0.2, but if we look each group, we can see that Setosa has 13/50=26% and Virginica 6/50=12%. There is any way I can have in every group a 20% sample?